# The Calendar Countdown code is not working

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I have this problem in Python. Yesterday, I copied the Countdown Calendar code in Coding Projects with Python and added the 'events.txt'. I checked all the problem to make sure it work. But when I ran it, the text isn't show up. Here is how my documents are set up:

[image: documents]

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from datetime import date, datetime

def get_events():
    list_events = []
    with open('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            current_event = line.split('.')
            event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
            current_event[1] = event_date
            list_events.append(current_event)
    return list_events

def days_between_dates(date1, date2):
    time_between = str(date1 - date2)
    number_of_days = time_between.split(' ')
    return number_of_days[0]

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, bg='black')
c.pack()
c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='w', fill='orange', \
              font='Arial 28 bold underline', text='My Countdown Calendar')

events = get_events()
today = date.today()
vertical_space = 100

for event in events:
    event_name = event[0]
    days_until = days_between_dates(event[1], today)
    display = 'It is %s days until %s' % (days_until, event_name)
    c.create_text(100, vertical_space, anchor='w', fill='lightblue', \
                  font='Arial 28 bold', text=display)
```

Comment: Could you give us the link to this countdown calendar, please?

Comment: You are placing all of your event texts at exactly the same coordinates.  You probably want to add something to `vertical_space` inside the final loop.

Comment: Since that's not all of the code I can't tell, but tkinter programs wouldn't work **at all** unless you call something like `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @icedwater It's in the book Coding Projects in Python.

Comment: @jasonharper Do you know how? Please copy the code, fix and post to me so that I can know better.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple things.

1. `current_event = line.split('.')` - I believe this should be a comma, not a period.
2. Like somebody else has mentioned, if using PyCharm, you need to add `root.mainloop()` to the end of your file.
3. Make sure your text file doesn't have any additional lines at the end and there are no spaces between the events and the event dates - just a comma.

I found that this fixed my issues when working on this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

you need root.mainloop() at the end of your code for it to run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).